# Want a readout from command prompt

Tags: batch-file

I currently have the simplest of simple batch files "ping 8.8.8.8" all it does is ping google 4 times, and report back the times, along with the minimum, maximum and average from the 4 pings. What I want to do is make it so that I can press a button on my keyboard (I have a blackwidow, with macros enabled) or maybe just open a program, and have it ping, then report back with only the max, min and average times, as an overlay in the corner. Is this possible within a batch file or do I have to move up to something more powerful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the format for a basic batch macro:

```
 Set _macro=For /l %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 (Echo Main MACRO goes here.) else setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ^& Set argv=, 

%_macro% arg1 arg2

 :: The macro will expand to:
 :: for /l %%n in (1 1 2) do if %%n==2 (Echo Main MACRO goes here.) else setlocal enableDelayedExpansion & Set argv=, arg1 arg2

 :: which is equivalent to:
 ::    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 ::    Set argv= arg1 arg2
 ::    Echo Main MACRO goes here.
```

If you aren't sure how to connect your keyboard as input or don't know what some of what this stuff means, I'd recommend googling it. The macro/modding community is pretty large nowadays and especially with a very well supported keyboard (like the Blackwidow) you should be set.